# Call a nested user-defined function prior to its definition

Tags: php

According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) calling a user-defined function prior to its definition doesn't produce an error except:

> When a function is defined in a conditional manner... Its definition must be processed prior to being called.

Example:

```
bar();
$makefoo = true;
if ($makefoo) {
    function bar() {
        echo "I don't exist.\n";
    }
}
```

Throws a Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bar() in...
```

With above explanation I suppose below code to produce the same error:

```
foo();
bar();
function foo() {
    $makefoo = true;
    if ($makefoo) {
        function bar() {
            echo "I don't exist until foo() is called.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

But [it doesn't](https://3v4l.org/WoECr). What am I missing in manuals that describes this behavior?

Comment: Do you understand the first behaviour? Or is that unclear as well?

Comment: 'Its definition must be processed prior to being called.' which in the second example, the function is defined before `bar()` is called (when you call `foo()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foo();
bar();
function foo() {
    $makefoo = true;
    if ($makefoo) {
        function bar() {
            echo "I don't exist until foo() is called.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

PHP code is executed in two passes: first the parsing and compilation step, then the runtime. Plain functions like `foo` can be defined at parse time; they're unconditional and not dependent on runtime information.

So `function foo` is defined at parse time, then at runtime `foo()` is called, which creates `function bar`, so then you can call `bar()` right afterwards.

Comment: That's one of pure moments of failure. I did ask the question prematurely without any understanding of code. Thank you